# livejquery is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using [livequery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery) for applying [jquery chosen plugin (for adding tags)](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) on dynamically added elements. I tried :

```
$(".chz").livequery(function () {
    $(this).chosen();
});
```

Through above code, choose plugin is not applying. But if i tried this :

```
$(".chz").livequery('click', function () {
    $(this).chosen();
});
```

Than it works properly. But in my case i can`t use click event because until user click over the element the plugin is not applied. What i am doing working in first case ?

Comment: I'm not sure livequery still works with the new jquery versions. Anyway your code seems fine. Try to check if it enters the event handler (write a console.log or an alert there).

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
  $("body").on('click', '.chz'function () {
    $(this).chosen();
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

when we use chosen plugin then we set class like this

```
 class ="chzn-select"
```

then

```
$(function() {
    $("chzn-select").chosen();
});
```

i think this will help you